# Adding jQueryui Buttons to dynamically added content

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I have a list of items that have some jQueryUI buttons associated with them. After an action (deleting an item) I want to reload the list via ajax.

Only problem is when I do so the JQueryUI buttons no longer show, just the standard markup.

I know I can use `jQuery.live()` for dynamically adding click handlers etc, but how do I apply a jQueryUI `button()` to them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you reload via ajax, call [`.button()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/) (or whatever variant you're using) in that [context](http://api.jquery.com/context/), like this:

```
$.ajax({
  //other options..
  success: function(data) {
    //insert elements
    $(".button", data).button();
  }
});
```

This will run `.button()` on elements **only in the response** (not the others already in the page/DOM elsewhere) with `class="button"`.

You can't really use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or anything like that here, that relies on event bubbling, not really anything to do with adding/removing elements...when it comes to plugins you need need to execute them again against the new elements you add.  Or, the less efficient but more generic approach would be the [`.livequery()` plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery/), used like this:

```
$(".button").livequery(function() {
  $(this).button();
});
```

As I said though, it's not the most efficient thing in the world, since it actually monitors the DOM for changes in various ways.

Comment: Cool thanks. So the short answer is - you can't unless you use the livequery plugin. Might check it out anyway but I take your point about efficiency if that's how it works.

Useful info about calling methods in context though - I think my main concern was avoiding re-running .button() on all the elements in the page, which you answered.

Comment: As side note to this answer, I had to to reverse the order for the "refresh" where it's $(".button", data).button(), I had to do $(data, ".button").button(), just in case someone else is trying and it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-bind the event handler with:

```
$("#mybutton").unbind().click(function(){ ..do..something... });
```

Comment: Nice thanks - but it's not just the event handler - jqueryui adds markup and other things for each button. otherwise I could just use live for the click handler. I'm trying to avoid using callback JS on top of jQuery.load() if possible.