# Add click function to dynamically created html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

So I have a div that contains a number of other divs. Each of these other divs has a class called record. I only use this class to select all of these divs.

```
<div id = "resultContainer">
   <div class="record">result1</div>
   <div class="record">result2</div>
   <div class="record">result3</div>
   <div class="record">result4</div>
</div>
```

I also add a click event=

```
$(".record").click(function(e) {
        do stuff here....
    });
```

Now I want to dynamically add another div.

```
$("#resultContainer").append("<div class='record'>result5>/div>");
```

But now that click event is not added to the record.

My idea was to create a function called `update()` that executed the `$(".record....` code and call the function each time I added a record. But then the original divs do the action more than once!

How do I get all of my divs, regardless of when they were added, to before the `do stuff here...` exactly once when clicked?

thanks!

In addition, I also have buttons on the dynamic div. So a solution that was able to handle something lik this: `$(".save").button({ icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-disk' }, text: false });` would be preferable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `.live()` in this case. This is a perfect situation for [jQuery's `.delegate()` method](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), which is more efficient.

```
$("#resultContainer").delegate('.record','click',function() {
    // do stuff here...
});
```

Only clicks inside the `resultContainer` need to be processed to see if they match `.record`, where `.live()` will need to process every click on the page.

Comment: The issue that I did have with this is that I had a lot of events, and the containers that I had to delegate too were too lagre. I had to go back to implementing the events normally and finding a different way to make sure the events were not applied twice. Good for most applications but it was too slow for me.

Comment: The problem is that this method does delays the "work" to "runtime" rather than "loadtime". So when I create some new html I would rather spend the time then applying the events to only the tags that it has not been applied to already, rather than spending the time when the user clicks to figure out if an event needs to be fired.

Answer (score 4):

http://api.jquery.com/live/:

> *Attach a handler to the event for all
>   elements which match the current
>   selector, now and in the future.*

```
$(".record").live("click", function(e) {
    //do stuff here... 
});
```

Comment: whats the cost of doing this however?

Comment: @kralco One event is attached to `document`. Check out the docs (http://api.jquery.com/live/) for more info.

Comment: is there a way to use this solution in this situation? `$(".save").button({ icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-disk' }, text: false });`

Comment: @kralco For `button()`, check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028912/adding-jqueryui-buttons-to-dynamically-added-content/3028958#3028958. Also, if all your records are in `resultContainer`, patrick dw is right -- use `delegate`.

Comment: @patrick - the difference being that delegate allows for adding the event to only a parent element, rather than the whole document? so something like `.delegate(document,'click',function...` would be equivilent to `.live('click',function...`?

Comment: @kralco626: They are nearly equivalent. Only difference at that point is that `.live()` requires an initial DOM selection of `$('.record')`, which it then discards (making it still less efficient). Functionally, they would be the same.

Comment: @Emmett - I read the solution on that question, is there a "now and in the future" solution for buttons?

Comment: @kralco No. You'd have to go with one of the solutions in that answer, e.g. the livequery plug-in.

Answer (score 2):

As of jQuery 1.7 you should use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `live()` or `delegate()`. From the documentation:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers.

The `on()` method should be attached to a static parent or `document`:

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.record', function(e) {
    // do stuff here....
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the jQuery live() function

http://api.jquery.com/live/

You can add an event listener for all div, regardless of changes in the page

Answer (score 0):

Try live() method. Instead of:

```
$(".record").click(function(e) {
    do stuff here....
});
```

Try this:

```
$(".record").live(function(e) {
    do stuff here....
});
```