# Jquery live() and jquery ui button()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to use jquery ui button for buttons created in future. can i use live()?
what is eventType in live()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download the .livequery() plugin, which should give you the same functionality:

```
$(".button").livequery(function() {
  $(this).button();
});
```

.livequery() plugin:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery

As far as I know there is no way to use live with the JQuery UI button. This SO question might also be helpful:
[Adding jQueryui Buttons to dynamically added content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028912/adding-jqueryui-buttons-to-dynamically-added-content)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this. The jquery ui button call adds "ui-button" as a class to either the element or the element's label (in the case of radio/checkbox). You can grab the elements with the "ui-button" class and do "live" functions against those elements.

So if your html is...

```
<div id="parent_div">
    <input type="checkbox" id="test_checkbox" />
    <label for="test_checkbox">Test</label>
</div>
```

then your script would be...

```
$(function() {
    $("#parent_div .ui-button").live("mouseenter", function (e) {
        // code to show something here
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this solution:

```
content.load('URL #sectionToLoad', function(event) {
    $("SELECTOR, button").button();
    ...
});
```

It's work fine

**UPDATE**

Use delegate to assign Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root elements. jQuery API: [link](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), instead of live method, and don´t forget to undelegate the event.

Hope this help you.