# jqueryui elements not loading on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am having a bit of a problem with jqueryui elements that are called from inside a script. They are not loading as jqueryui elements. I think i need to somehow call the jquery script again but i am not too sure how to go about this.

the button click code is

```
$("#parcels-add").click(function () {
    //remove existing table rows if there are any
    $("#added-parcels tr td").remove();
    $("#parcel").css("display", "block");
    //Add the rows
    for (var i = 0; i < numOfParcels; i++) {
       $("#added-parcels").prepend("<tr>" +
                                   "<td>" + "01" + "</td>" +
                                   "<td><input type='text' value='cm' class='package-value' /></td>" +
                                   "<td><input type='text' value='cm' class='package-value' /></td>" +
                                   "<td><input type='text' value='cm' class='package-value' /></td>" +
                                   "<td><input type='text' value='cm' class='package-value' /></td>" +
                                   "<td><button id='package-delete'>Delete</button></td>") +
                                 "</tr>";
      }
});
```

The button in the for loop is not displaying like the rest of the jqueryui buttons. as seen below 
[image]

It looks and acts like a normal HTML button

[image]

I also have a simple script to remove the text in the input text box's which is not working

Would this maybe have something to do with the ordering of the javascript files? There is no error in the chrome console but this is not working as it should.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot have multiple buttons (or elements) with the same id.

Comment: Please post HTML code and preferably on jsfiddle.

Comment: You are removing the cells and not the rows, change it to: `$("#added-parcels tr").remove();` (this won't fix the main issue)

Comment: Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RRcHD/4/). Its seems to works but if you see the //<!-- Textbox hide values --> script is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `.button()` on the new buttons after the `for` loop.

```
 $("#added-parcels button").button();
```

Comment: The same applies for every jQuery UI element: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028912/adding-jqueryui-buttons-to-dynamically-added-content

Comment: Sweet!! Thank you and then obviously call any other custom script functions that apply to that code block as well.